# Count columns in each grid row - Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, grid, css-grid

Is it possible to count columns in each grid row? Rows can be dynamic.

```js
let grid = document.querySelector('.grid');
let columns = document.querySelectorAll('.column');
let button = document.querySelector('button');
```

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  justify-items: start;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid div {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  width: 100%;
}

.grid > *:nth-child(3n-1):nth-last-of-type(1) {
  border-color: red;
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.grid > *:nth-child(3n-2):nth-last-of-type(1) {
  border-color: red;
  grid-column: span 3;
}

.grid > *:nth-child(3n-1) {
  justify-self: center;
}

.grid > *:nth-child(3n) {
  justify-self: end;
}

.result {
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin: 10px 0;
}

button {
  margin: 40px 0;
}

p {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column">1</div>
  <div class="column">2</div>
  <div class="column">3</div>
  <div class="column">4</div>
</div>

<br />

Row 2
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column">1</div>
  <div class="column">2</div>
</div>
<br />

<div class="result">
  <p>Row 1:</p>
  <small>Columns:</small><br />
</div>
<div class="result">
  <p>Row 2:</p>
  <small>Columns:</small><br />
</div>
```

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-1hzwpx?file=index.html

Comment: your are already filtering you child via css to have them span or not a few columns, use the same idea with your js from the child.length and grid-template-columns value you have set. offsetWidth from the parent or the children can do too. What have you tried so far ? *(you posted a similar question a few hours ago or was it someone else ?)*

Answer (score 1):

Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to select all elements with class `column`, then get the [length of the NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/length):

```js
const columns = document.querySelectorAll('.grid .column').length
console.log(columns)
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="column">1</div>
  <div class="column">2</div>
  <div class="column">3</div>
  <div class="column">4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, I added an id to the first grid tag:

```html
Row 1
<div class="grid" id="grid-1">
  <div class="column">1</div>
  <div class="column">2</div>
  <div class="column">3</div>
  <div class="column">4</div>
</div>
```

```js
const grid1 = document.getElementById('grid-1');

// logs the number of columns in the first grid
console.log(grid1.children.length)
```

Just adapt it to your need.